# Return from method if other method succeeds with one line

Tags: python, python-decorators, program-flow

I have trouble finding a fitting title for this question, so please forgive me.

Many methods in my class look like this:

```
def one_of_many():
    # code to determine `somethings`
    for something in somethings:
        if self.try_something(something):
            return
    # code to determine `something_else`
    if self.try_something(something_else):
        return
    …
```

where `self.try_something` returns `True` or `False`.

Is there a way to express this with something like:

```
def one_of_many():
    # code to determine `somethings`
    for something in somethings:
        self.try_something_and_return(something) # this will return from `one_of_many` on success
    # code to determine `something_else`
    self.try_something_and_return(something_else) # this will return from `one_of_many` on success
    …
```

I was fiddling with decorators and context managers to make this happen with no success but I still believe that "There must be a better way!".

Comment: You can stuff `if self.try_something(something): return` onto one line just like that, by moving `return` onto the same line, but it doesn't really help readability most of the time. Trying to have a `try_something_and_return` method that returns on behalf of its caller would be even worse.

Comment: @Davit I want it to just return (as in the first code snippet).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `itertools` to the rescue:

When you say method, I assume this is a method of a class so the code could look like this:

```
import itertools

class Thing:
    def one_of_many(self):
        # code to determine `somethings`
        for something in itertools.chain(somethings,[something_else]):
            if self.try_something(something):
                return
```

Hopefully `something_else` is not too difficult to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this mcve mimics your problem:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = 3
def f(thing):
    print(thing)
    return False

class F:
    pass

self = F()
self.trysomething = f
```

Map the method to all the things and take action if any return `True`

```
if any(map(self.trysomething, a + [b])):
    print('yeay')
else:
    print('nay')
```

Depending on what `a` and `b` actually are you may have to play around with ways to concatenate or flatten/add or chain as @quamrana mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
if self.try_something(a_thing) or self.try_something(another_thing):
    return
```

But you'll either need to know your `thing`'s beforehand.. or calculate them with an expression within the function call.